# Retrieve data from a Xamarin.Android webview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

I´m making a native application in android using Xamarin.Android and my problem is that i can´t figure out how to retrieve data from a webview.

In this case I need to retrieve the users mail from the DOM loaded in the webview.

So far I´ve searched in the Xamarin forums and the best option I found was using a HybridWebView in Xamarin.Forms, as stated in the [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/)